# Make command line app behave like a normal macOS app?

Tags: applications

Is it possible to make a command line app  behave and act like a normal Cocoa app?

I want to be able to set command line app [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/), for example, as a default pdf viewer.

I want it to appear in Alfred/Spotlight when I search for it, and if an instance is already running, typing "Zathura" and then Return would bring up that instance instead starting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question... an application written for the command line is not a Cocoa app, so it won’t behave like one.

Apps designed to run in the GUI environment of macOS has a “payload” attached to them including a plist that “describes” it to the OS and is used in registering the app with [LaunchServicres](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services).  Zathura has none of this.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) which will take shell scripts or python scripts and make them into an app that you can just double click to run. The app is free. I use it to convert python scrips but it also works for command line scripts.

Comment: Tried Platupus. It's pretty cool.  Thank you for telling me about it. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to achieve what I wanted (due to specifics of how Zathura gets packaged for OSX) but it's a pretty neat app.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Natsfan's information I got to Platypus. If you still didn't solve this issue, here are what I did to achieve it.

[image: some settings]

1. give your app a name
2. select Interface None
3. check "Accept dropped items
4. Make sure "Remain running after execution
5. click "Edit"
6. paste the codes into editor

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# replace the zathura *absolute path* if it's not in your case
# don't forget to put single quotes around $1, otherwise you will not be able to open files with space in names
# also the last "&" mark is necessary, without it you can only open one zathura window.

/bin/bash -exec "/opt/homebrew/bin/zathura '$1'" &
```

[image: codes]

7. click "settings", then check "accept dropped files".
   [image: settings]
8. create app
9. You may also need to codesign the app

Enjoy!!!